# Override widget.css for yotpo in default magento

Tags: magento2, css, review, product-review

Can we override yotpo css named widget.css in the default magento?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not override with usuall theme inheritance:
Create file:

```
app/design/frontend/{ThemeVendor}/{ThemeName}/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

and put your styles there with higher [css specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp).

P.S. {Value} means something what you have to replace with your own value